# JS get random value from array and update array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I need your help on this!
I'm generating an array which corresponds to a question number.

```
var arrayCharge = [];
for (var i = 2; i <= 45; i++) {
arrayCharge.push(i);
}
```

then I use this number to append the corresponding question, answer then click.
Then I'm getting a new value from the array like this

```
const randomQ = arrayCharge;
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomQ.length);
```

It works and a new question is charged but the array is still the same.
I've tried this

```
var remQ = arrayCharge.indexOf(randomQ[random]);
arrayCharge.splice(remQ,1);
```

But It doesn't work ;-(

Thanks a lot for your help.
Nicolas

Here is the entire code to help comprehension! sorry for that, I should have done it from the begining.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Hyperspace by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @ajlkn
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>

<head>
    <title>Repérez vos messages contraignants - Quiz</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
</head>

<body class="is-preload">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <!-- <section id="sidebar">
    </section> -->
    <!-- Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Intro -->
        <section id="intro" class="wrapper style1 fullscreen fade-up">
            <div class="inner">
                <header>
                    <button id="start">Commencer</button>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </header>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <p id="Qnum"></p>
                    <p id="Q" data-qnumber="" data-type=""></p>
                    <section id="answer">
                        <input type="submit" id="1" name="R1" value="Non">
                        <input type="submit" id="2" name="R2" value="Parfois">
                        <input type="submit" id="3" name="R3" value="Souvent">
                        <input type="submit" id="4" name="R4" value="Oui">
                    </section>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            if (localStorage.getItem("clic") >= 45) {
                console.log('45');
                sessionStorage.clear();
                localStorage.clear();
            }

            var Q1 = [1, "My first question", "FP"];
            var Q2 = [2, "My second question", "SP"];
            var Q3 = [3, "My third question", "SE"];
            var Q4 = [4, "My foutrh question", "DP"];
            var Q5 = [5, "My fifth question", "FP"];    
            //etc... until Q45


            if (sessionStorage.getItem("FP") == null) {

                $("form").attr("action", "driversV2.php");
                $("#answer").hide();
                $("#start").click(function() {

                    $("#Qnum").append(1+" / 45");
                    $("#Q").append(Q1[1]).attr("data-qnumber", Q1[0]).attr("data-type", Q1[2]);
                    $("#answer").show();
                    $("header").hide();

                    var pageType = $("#Q").attr("data-type");
                    $("input").click(function() {
                        var reponse = this.id;
                        sessionStorage.setItem(pageType, reponse);
                        localStorage.setItem("clic", 1);
                    });
                });

            } else {
                $("header").hide();
                var clicNum = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clic"));
                var QNumber = clicNum + 1;
                var arrayCharge = [];
                for (var i = 2; i <= 45; i++) {
                  arrayCharge.push(i);
                }
                const randomQ = arrayChargeNew;
                const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomQ.length);
                console.log('valeur random new = '+randomQ[random]);
                var QCharge = "Q" + randomQ[random];
                var Charge = eval(QCharge);
                localStorage.setItem("random",randomQ[random]);
   
                $("#Qnum").append(QNumber+" / 45");
                $("#Q").append(Charge[1]).attr("data-qnumber", Charge[0]).attr("data-type", Charge[2]);
                //création de la variable du type de question
                var pageType = $("#Q").attr("data-type");
                //alert(sessionStorage.getItem(pageType));
                if (localStorage.getItem("clic") < 44) {

                    $("form").attr("action", "driversV2.php");

                    if (sessionStorage.getItem(pageType) != null) {
                        var x = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem(pageType));
                        $("input").click(function() {
                            var reponse = parseInt(this.id);
                            var addition = reponse + x;
                            sessionStorage.setItem(pageType, addition);
                            var clic = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clic"));
                            localStorage.setItem("clic", clic + 1);
                        });
                    } else {
                        $("input").click(function() {
                            var reponse = this.id;
                            sessionStorage.setItem(pageType, reponse);
                            var clic = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clic"));
                            localStorage.setItem("clic", clic + 1);

                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    $("form").attr("action", "driversResultat.php");

                    if (sessionStorage.getItem(pageType) != null) {
                        var x = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem(pageType));
                        $("input").click(function() {
                            var reponse = parseInt(this.id);
                            var addition = reponse + x;
                            sessionStorage.setItem(pageType, addition);
                            var clic = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clic"));
                            localStorage.setItem("clic", clic + 1);

                        });
                    } else {
                        $("input").click(function() {
                            var reponse = this.id;
                            sessionStorage.setItem(pageType, reponse);
                            var clic = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clic"));
                            localStorage.setItem("clic", clic + 1);

                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what doesn't work exactly? We need probably more context for example how is `arrayCharge` used?

Comment: In fact I use the "randomQ[random]" and I want to remove iot from the array when the question has been asked.
Each question lokks like this : 
var Q45 = [45, "Je pense qu'on peut s'améliorer en travaillant dur.", "FE"];
var QCharge = "Q" + randomQ[random];
var Charge = eval(QCharge);
$("#Q").append(Charge[1]).attr("data-qnumber", Charge[0]).attr("data-type", Charge[2]);

Comment: I think it is because you are confusing `random` and index.  Your last block of code tries to find the index for a **value** that matches the random number.  BUT, the random number is based on the length of the array.  Therefore, a random number may already have been removed from the array as a **value** but still exist as a index number OR may exist as a **value** but not as an index number

Comment: In fact, I'm using the index of the value to remove it from the original array

Comment: Yes, but the **random** number is based on the length of the array NOT the **values** in the array.

Comment: Why not simply pick a random number based on the length of the array and remove the item at that index point - does it matter what the **value** is?

Comment: To put it another way...  If you start with [0,1,2,3] and your random number is 1, you remove the item with a value of 1 and are left with [0,2,3].  Your next random number is also 1.  What happens next?

Comment: But I want the next random value to be different from 1 and picked up in the new array [0,2,3].

Comment: Exactly - you can not generate a random number based on the **length** of the array **AND** assume that it also exists as a **value** in the array

Comment: @ATD So what should I change? what do you suggest?

Comment: I have posted an answer with one possible solution - with comments to explain what I think you need to do and when

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm trying to make it work and I will get back to you with champagne ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicolas, this is the sort of thing you should end up with:

```js
// From my library js file
// returns a random number in the given range
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// Variables for objects that need to be available throughout
let availableQuestions = [];
let rnd = 0;
let counter = 0;

// Populate the question array - how this is done depends on where the question data comes from
function createQuestions() {
  availableQuestions.length = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    availableQuestions.push({"questionnumber": i, "question": "Text for question " + i});
  }
}

// Pick a random question and display that to the user
function getRandomQuestion() {
  let osQuestions = availableQuestions.length;
  let qnElement = document.getElementById("questionnumber");
  let qElement = document.getElementById("question");
  let sButton = document.getElementById("submit");
  let rButton = document.getElementById("restart");
  // If there are no more questions, stop
  if (osQuestions == 0) {
    qnElement.innerHTML = "Finished!";
    qElement.innerHTML = "";
    sButton.style.display = "none";
    rButton.style.display = "inline";
  } else {
    // display a sequential question number rather than the actual question number
    counter++;
    rnd = getRandomNumber(0, osQuestions - 1);
    let thisQuestion = availableQuestions[rnd];
    qnElement.innerHTML = "Question: " + counter + " (Actually question: " + thisQuestion.questionnumber + ")";
    qElement.innerHTML = thisQuestion.question;
  }
}

// Process the user's answer and remove the question from the array
function submitAnswer() {
  // ALSO Add in what needs to be done to update backend database etc when the user clicks submit
  availableQuestions.splice(rnd, 1);
  getRandomQuestion();
}

// Reset everything - for testing purposes only
function restart() {
  let qnElement = document.getElementById("questionnumber");
  let qElement = document.getElementById("question");
  let sButton = document.getElementById("submit");
  let rButton = document.getElementById("restart");
  qnElement.innerHTML = "";
  qElement.innerHTML = "";
  sButton.style.display = "inline";
  rButton.style.display = "none";
  // Reset the displayed question number counter
  counter = 0;
  createQuestions();
  getRandomQuestion();
}

// Needed to populate the array and display the first question
function runsetup() {
  createQuestions();
  getRandomQuestion();
}

window.onload = runsetup;
```

```html
<div id="questionnumber"></div>
<hr>
<div id="question"></div>

<button id="submit" onclick="submitAnswer();">Submit</button>
<button id="restart" onclick="restart();" style="display:none;">Restart</button>
```

I've included a counter variable so that the user does't see the actual question number - just 1, 2, 3 etc but I've shown the actual question number so that you can see it working

Comment: Wahou!! You're fantastic. Thank you so much. I'm on this for few days and it's very interesting to see how you do things, much to learn for me.

Comment: :D np - the next step is to think about what happens if the user reloads the page half way through answering the questions.  But that becomes easier to think about once you have the basic variables and functions structure in place.

Comment: Then I can store the last question number he answered. Sure with the above code that a question will appear just once?

Comment: You would need to store all of the questions that have been answered and, when he reloads the page, retrieve that stored list, read it find the question numbers answered and use that to remove the matching items from the availableQuestions array before displaying the next question.

Answer (score 0):

Nicolas, this is what I think you should be doing:

```js
// Create the array in whatever way you need to
var arrayCharge = [];
for (var i = 2; i <= 45; i++) {
  arrayCharge.push({"questionnumber": i, "question": "Text of question " + i});
}

// Just confirm the length of the array - should be 44
console.log(arrayCharge.length);
// Generate a random number based on the length of the array
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayCharge.length);

// Get the question at the randomly generated index number
let thisQuestion = arrayCharge[rnd];
// Check that we have a random question
console.log(thisQuestion.questionnumber);
console.log(thisQuestion.question)

// Present the question to the user on the page
// The user completes question and clicks "Submit"

// Now remove the question, using the SAME index number
arrayCharge.splice(rnd,1);
// Check that the array has lost an entry - the size should now be 43
console.log(arrayCharge.length);
```

Comment: Hello ATD,Thank you again for this solution, it's much better like this to create the array with questions directly. Still have a problem when submiting the "rnd" is removed but when I submit again the new question, it removes the actual "rnd" but the previous came back on list and it can pick this question again.

Comment: That entirely depends on how and when the submit takes place.  If the user actually submits a form that triggers a refresh of the page, then the question will reappear because you are reloading the page.  If, however, the page is not submitted at that point, the rnd variable will remain as long as it has been defined outside of a function - and is, therefore, a global variable available until the window is closed.  So, what happens when they submit their answer?

Comment: I will change that, thanks a lot, I think I have all I need here. Great!!

Comment: Last comment, the creation of the array needs to be outside of the function or inside ?

Comment: The variables should be outside of a function - that way they can be used anywhere in your code.  Functions should be there to generate or control things.  The above works because we are only working on a cut-down version of your entire code.  So, put all of the variables at the top of your code.  Create functions to generate the questions array, get a random number, extract the random question, populate the page and to remove the question from the array when the user clicks Submit.  Then, when the page loads or the user is ready for the next question, you just call the appropriate functions.

Comment: Very clear, I will do that. And I was also thinking that give the question a random number would be even easier because no need to remove the item.

Comment: You don't need to give each question a random number.  Consider using a counter - the first question they see (no matter what your question number may be) is shown as Question 1, the next is Question 2 and so on.

Comment: I've just added a new answer showing an example of what you should be aiming for.  Obviously, your code would be more complicated than this, but it should give you the idea of the structure you need.  The code is in a snippet, so you can test it if you like.  I've included a counter as described in my previous comment.